# Replace faulty video on YouTube

Tags: youtube

I have seen a mistake in one of a series of seven videos I've uploaded to YouTube. They have been recently posted and don't have "likes", comments etc, so I am perfectly happy to start from scratch.

All I want to do is delete number five in the series and upload a new number 5. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to replace a video you uploaded on Youtube. You can upload the better video and edit the original's notes and annotations to get people to go to the new video, however

Exerpt from [Source](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=58101)

> There is currently no way to replace an old video with a new one while still retaining the original view count, comments or ratings.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't mind starting from scratch, I would say just delete and upload the corrected version with the same title and description. Since the URL might have changed, playlists will no longer work with the old video, but you can update those playlists to point to the new video you have.